# Permutation on n objects decomposed into disjoint cycles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have a $n$ objects that are decomposed into cycles of size $\nu, \nu=1,\dots n$ where we have $k_\nu$ of each size cycle (i.e. $k_1 + 2k_2 + \dots nk_n = n$). I am told that if we take the number of permutations on the whole thing we should get

\begin{equation}
n! \prod_{\nu=1}^n \nu^{-k_\nu}(k_\nu!)^{-1}
\end{equation}

Can anybody explain the intuition to me here? I've never been good at combinatorics!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is correct if by "permutations on the whole thing" you mean the number of permutations of $n$ things that have the given cycle structure.  As an example, let us consider permutations of $5$ things that break down as a single $2$ cycle and a $3$ cycle.  The number of those is ${5 \choose 2}(2!-1)(3!-1)=50$ because we can choose the two items to be in the two cycle, then there are $2!-1$ ways to shift the two cycle (we can't have the identity because that would give us two one cycles) and $3!-1$ ways to position the three cycle.  Your formula gives $5!\frac 12\cdot \frac 13=20$ because for $\nu=2,3$ we have $k_2=1, k_3=1$.  If I have misinterpreted the question please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As a concrete example let's count the permutations of $[8]$ that have cycle structure $z_2^1z_3^2$ that is

$$k_i=\begin{cases}& 1\qquad i=2\\& 2\qquad i=3\\& 0\qquad \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Then our cycles look like

$$(\bullet\: \bullet\: \bullet)(\bullet\: \bullet\: \bullet)(\bullet\: \bullet)$$

We can replace $\bullet$s with our $8$ numbers in $8!$ ways but then we note that some cycles are counted multiple times, such as

$$(1\: 2\: 3)(4\: 5\: 6)(7\: 8)\quad \text{and}\quad (4\: 5\: 6)(1\: 2\: 3)(7\: 8)$$

so we must divide out the ways we can permute equal length cycles, in this case there are $2$ cycles length $3$ and $1$ cycle of length $2$ so we divide $2!\cdot 1!$.

Note also that, once we have divided out repeats due to equal length cycles we will still have repeat cycles as, for example

$$(1\: 2\: 3)(4\: 5\: 6)(7\: 8)$$
$$(3\: 1\: 2)(4\: 5\: 6)(7\: 8)$$
$$(2\: 3\: 1)(4\: 5\: 6)(7\: 8)$$

are all the same permutation, hence we must divide again, this time by the lengths of each cycle i.e. by $3^2\cdot 2$. So in this case we get

$$\text{permutations of $[8]$ with cycle structure $z_2^1z_3^2$}=\frac{8!}{2!\cdot 1!\cdot 3^2\cdot 2}$$

You should be able to see that for a general cycle structure you get your quoted result.

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant Thank you. The paper is really unclear so I was completely lost! Thanks again :)

Comment: You are most welcome!